# NoClassDefFoundError with a long classname on Tomcat with java 1.4.2_07-b05

Tags: java, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror, classname

I have a java class:

> it.eng.ancona.view.RuoliView$TabElaborazioneFattureValidazione$ElencoDettaglioElaborazioneFattureValidazione$RigaElencoDettaglioElaborazioneFattureValidazione

It's so long for multiple inner class.

If I use 1.4.2_07-b05 on Eclipse and I call this class, all goes fine.

If I use 1.4.2_07-b05 on Tomcat 5.0 it throws `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I try to cut the class name, and after this all works fine.

I've searched the internet and I've found that the max length for a class name is 65000, so the length should be ok. And on eclipse all works.

The OS is Vista.

Someone know if it's a bug or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by the maximum path length of Windows. Try moving your Tomcat server to something like C:\TC to see if you still have a problem. Also check if the jar that this class should be in, actually does have it.

Answer (score 0):

isn't this more a Classpath problem?

Within Eclipse it is fairly easy to get a correct classpath, since it manages its own build directory.

Is the class in your WAR (or autodeploy-folder, or whatever you use to deploy to Tomcat)?